# How to get selected data from oracle in php

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I want to get some data from my oracle database into php through a html form where I search by a string which exists into a column. I have the following php code and the search form retuns nothing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
if(preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]+/", $_POST['name'])){
$name=$_POST['name'];
// Connects to the XE service (i.e. database) on the "localhost" machine
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pwd', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT  deejays.name,available_dates.data,available_dates.venue,available_dates.location FROM deejays,available_dates WHERE deejays.name LIKE '%W&W%' and pk_id=fk_id');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

}
else{
echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
}
}
}
?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I want is for i.e the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query to include bindable parameters.  Here is part of [example 4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#example-2186) from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for the `oci_bind_name` function, which you simply need to adapt to suit your application:

```
$sql = 'SELECT last_name FROM employees WHERE department_id = :didbv ORDER BY last_name';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$didbv = 60;
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':didbv', $didbv);
oci_execute($stid);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
    echo $row['LAST_NAME'] ."<br>\n";
}
```

The documentation includes a very good description of what binding is, how to do it, and why it's important for application performance and security.